# How to search in folder excluding subfolders?

Tags: batch-file

Currently I am using this batch script and it loops through all subfolders, but I don't want that. I want it to only loop through the main folder and not subfolder.

```
%1 is the folder path for file search
set SIGNTOOL="%~dp0Signtool.exe"
set PFXFILE="%~dp0Temporary_Signing.pfx"
set PASSWORD=12345
SET FILES="%~dp0Signing_Files_List.txt"
set TIMESTAMP="http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll"
set "FILESPATH=%1"


FOR /F "delims= " %%a IN ('type %FILES%') DO (
FOR %FILESPATH% %%f IN (%%a) DO (
    %SIGNTOOL% sign /f %PFXFILE% /P %PASSWORD% /t %TIMESTAMP% %%f
)
)
```

Gives error at FOR %FILESPATH% %%f IN (%%a) DO

> %FILESPATH% was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've omitted to include data samples, it's not clear what you are trying to do.

```
FOR %FILESPATH% %%f IN (%%a) DO (
```

You appear to have modified a `for /r` here since you are referring to subdirectories.

Perhaps

```
FOR %%f IN (%FILESPATH%\%%a) DO (
```

will scan yor files. you will probably need to use `%FILESPATH%\%%f` instead of `%%f` in your `sign` line.